# Dynamic Event Handler lost after postback

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a asp.net page with a button, the event the button needs to perform on it's click event needs to vary, dependant on what options are selected further up the page. The button itself is included in the master page, and it's actions are affected by selections made in the child page.

To do this, I have a method in the master page, that is called by the child page, when a users presses a button, that passes the Eventhandler to be used by that button, that is then assigned to masterpage eventhandler for that button:

```
  public void assignEvent( EventHandler saveEvent)
    {
            this.SaveButtonEvent+= saveEvent
    }
```

Then, when the save button on the master page, it calls that eventhandler

```
protected void save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.SaveButtonEvent != null)
        {
            this.SaveButtonEvent(this, e);
        }
    }
```

The event handler is assigned ok in the first section of code, however because pressing the save button causes a postback, the SaveButtonEvent event handler is set back to being null, and so nothing happens.

How can I preserve the contents of SaveButtonEvent Event Handler during postback, or is there a better way to be doing this?

**EDIT:**

I can get this to work by saving the EventHandler to the session, but this doesn't seem like a great idea.

Comment: Can you show how you create the button? Declaratively or programmatically? If so where in the Page Live Cylce?

Comment: Alternatively you could use the CommandArgument of a Button (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.commandargument.aspx) and then have a case handling your various options.

Answer (score 0):

When the user presses the button in the child page, store a value (in the viewstate) indicating what event handler should be passed. Then, in the load event of the child page, if it is a postback, always check the stored value and assign the event handler accordingly by calling the master page method.